# elasticsearch logstash delete when does not exist in input

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, command-line, logstash

I have an elasticsearch database and i want to delete all documents if not exists in input statement?
Can you help me please,

Thanks in advance

```
input {
jdbc {
    jdbc_validate_connection => true
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://xxxx:xxxx/xxxx"
    jdbc_user => "xxxx"
    jdbc_password => "xxxx"
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/Drivers/postgres/postgresql-9.4.1212.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    statement => "SELECT acso.usagers.id as id FROM acso.usagers WHERE acso.usagers.date_suppression is null"
    tags => ["idUsagers"]
}}  filter {}output {
elasticsearch {
    action => delete
    index => "usagers"
    document_type => "atms"
    doc_as_upsert => true
    document_id => "%{id}"
    hosts => "xxxxxx.example.org"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to delete any documents from ES that are not returned by your JDBC query.  If that's correct, I see two options:

- run the query, put the results into a new index, and use that index for queries.  You can create an [index alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) to hide the actual index name from your application if needed.
- run the query and [update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-action) any document in ES to show that they still exist.  [Delete](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) the documents that are not marked.